# Drop duplicates fom dataframe - Frequency for RFM Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm doing RFM Analysis on [Online Retail Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Online+Retail).

[image]

I want to calculate the Frequency per customer.

FREQUENCY (F) is: Total number of purchases.

To do that, I applied this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00352/Online%20Retail.xlsx'
    retail_df = pd.read_excel(url)
retail_uk = retail_df[retail_df['Country']=='United Kingdom']
frequency_df = retail_uk.groupby(by=['CustomerID'], as_index=False)['InvoiceNo'].count()
frequency_df.columns = ['CustomerID','Frequency']
frequency_df.head()
#remove duplicate of InvoiceNo by CustomerID
```

However, I'm not sure if this contains duplicates or not. I think yes because in the dataset there can be possible to have same **InvoiceNo** and **CustomerID** in case there is more than one product purchased. So, how to remove duplicates?

Comment: So duplicates have to be removed if they have the just the same InvoiceNo and CustomerID?

Comment: yes because it's one purchase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 frequency_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['InvoiceNo', 'CustomerID'], keep="first", inplace=True)
```